# How to detect when a user does not tap into a notification? (Xcode 8, iOS 10)

Tags: swift, notifications, unusernotificationcenter

I'm working with local notifications again and with the new `UserNotifications` framework, and I just want to ask is there a way to detect when the user does NOT tap into a notification?

Comment: There's no any way to detect something like that.

Comment: How do other apps handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment, this is not something available in the `UserNotifications` framework.